# Android OwnCloud Apache HttpClient

Tags: java, android, owncloud

I'm working on adding OwnCloud functionality to an app and I've been having some trouble. I'm getting this error:

```
Error:(45, 21) error: cannot access HttpClient
class file for org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient not found
```

at this line:

```
serverClient.setCredentials(
    OwnCloudCredentialsFactory.newBasicCredentials(USER, PASS));
```

Apparently apache commons is deprecated but the OwnCloud library is built using this. Suggestions?

Edit: Here's the OwnCloud [client source](https://github.com/owncloud/android-library/blob/master/src/com/owncloud/android/lib/common/OwnCloudClient.java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Third party libraries

ownCloud Android Library uses Apache JackRabbit, version 2.2.5. Copyright (C) 2004-2010 The Apache Software Foundation. Licensed under Apache License, Version 2.0.

Apache JackRabbit depends on Commons HTTPClient version 3.1 and SLF4j version 1.7.5; both included also. Copyright (C) 2004-2010 The Apache Software Foundation. Licensed under Apache License, Version 2.0.

I included the libraries and linked to them in Android Studio. Build went through.